# How to Create a SoapClient Object without Service Tag in WSDL Document?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, onvif

I am trying to implement an ONVIF client on PHP 7.4 with [SOAP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). I thought like it should be pretty straightforward, but I am stuck at first stage. My example code is below.

```
<?php

use SoapClient;

$client = new SoapClient("http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl", ["cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, "location" => "http://192.168.1.55/onvif/device_service"]);
```

This code throws SoapFault exception with *SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't bind to service* message. Seems like it looks for a service tag in WSDL document but it can't find. So my question is, how can I make it work without customize the original document? Or do I have to customize the original document and add service tag?